# Twitter integration on iOS < 5 with ARC

Tags: ios, twitter, automatic-ref-counting

I'm integrating my iOS app with Twitter, and I am using ARC.
I can use the default framework for iOS 5+, but for the previous versions I need something else.

I've been trying MGTwitterEngine, ShareKit and other libraries, but all of them do not use ARC. Is there any good, ARC compatible library out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use non ARC code in iOS 5.  You can mark files to not use ARC using the compiler flag '-fno-objc-arc'.  Under your targets go into the 'Build Phases' tab.  The second menu is called 'Compile Sources'.  Double click on each source file you know doesn't support ARC and type in the above '-fno-objc-arc' and you should be all set.